# How to give Pull request right to a user without giving access to repo in gitlab

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I have a private repository in gitlab. Can I give a user Pull request right without giving access to repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To create a pull request, a user would need to be able to view the original repository to create the branch that they're asking the repo owner to merge.

(In other words: You can't suggest changes to code that you can't view!)